# Using gameKit peer-to-peer connectivity when app is in background (e.g. while multitasking)

Tags: ios, background, sleep, multitasking, gamekit

I am trying to build an app that will use the game kit peer-to-peer connectivity on the iPhone in order to find other people around you who are using the app and exchange information with them.

My question is- is it possible to use peer-to-peer connectivity when app is running in the background and when iPhone is asleep? If yes, do I need to do anything special?

Also, Will I be able to use geo-location, local notification and HTTP request when app is running in the background/ when iPhone is in sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

The background mode in iOS is very restrictive.

When your application moving to the background you have a "finite-length time" granted by the OS to let you finish the work properly (finish a download, save a file, close some connections, etc.). After that you can do nothing expect for some long tasks permit by iOS.
The only long task that iOS lets you run are the:

- audio
- geo-location
- voip
- newsstand
- external-accessory
- bluetooth-central

([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20))

So if you use the peer-to-peer connectivity over the bluetooth you may (in theory) do that in the background mode. This is the same for the geo-location.

However if you want use the local notification you'll need to register them before moving to the background, and the same for the HTTP requests.
For more information check this doc: [App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).